# How to send files to the controller using multipart FormData() on an iPad in Safari

Tags: ios, ajax, ipad

My fellow coder and I are having issues sending some image uploads to the MVC controller via a multipart FormData() element. What we currently have set up has been tested on a windows desktop using the latest versions of Chrome, IE, Edge, Firefox, and Opera without any issues.

Below is the JavaScript and ajax we are using. We have multiple file inputs that accept multiple image files. The loop below goes through and individually appends each file from each input.

```
var index = 0;
var data = new FormData();
data.append("datalist", JSON.stringify(formInfo)); //list of objects
data.append("form", JSON.stringify(headerInfo));   //object

var images = document.getElementsByClassName("ImageUpload");
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++){
    var files = $(images[i]).prop("files");
    if (files != null && files.length > 0){
        for (var e = 0; e < files.length; e++){
            //append the image with a filename
            data.append("image" + ++index, files[e]);
        }
    }
}
UpdateData(data);

function UpdateData(datalist) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("UpdateData", "Home")',
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        datatype: "JSON",
        data: datalist,
        success: function (result) {
            //do stuff
        }
    });
}
```

In the controller, we are getting the information through Request.Form and Request.Files. As I mentioned, we are not having any problems other than on the iPad. When using the iPad, all it does is hang there, and does not even hit the controller. We do not have access to a Mac machine, so we can't hook up the iPad to use developer tools. The iPad has the latest version of IOS and has all app updates installed. We have spent a good portion of the afternoon trying various methods we found online, and even gave the google chrome app a whirl. But alas, we have been left to scratch our heads. Any help or information would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.